# sqlalchemy + sqlite + multiprocessing gives DetachedInstance error - sometimes

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I have a problem with using Sqlalchemy and multiprocessing with Sqlite. I am using default NullPool. I create a session in main process and pass it to multiple workers and  the entities are also passed to workers through same queue.

sporadically I hit a detached instance error inside workers,. Workers and master share the same session instance.I have tried several times to reproduce, the issue is not reproducible at will. Any suggestions on how to attack this issue will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use scoped session? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/contextual.html It seems that it incapsulates creating of new session instance in each new thread (or process as I understand). 
Check if it helps you.